# Debugging the low performance of home internet

Tags: networking, router, performance, wireless-router

Movie streaming performance on my bedtime tablet went bad recently. Last night, I even gave up on the next episode of my favorite series and tried to figure out what's wrong. Is it my home router's fault or is it my ISP's fault, was the question I had in mind.

I'm debugging using the following. Two wifi-connected laptops run `iperf` between each other and each of them runs the Ookla speed test.

1. Ookla speed test results vary a lot, from 11/55 Mbps (upstream/downstream) to 6/12 Mbps in just a couple of seconds.
2. Sometimes, my Ookla speed tests are better than what `iperf` measures. For instance, the speed test measures 11/24 Mbps while `iperf` measures 9/17 Mbps.
3. `ping` time from one of my laptops to the other goes from 2 ms to 200 ms while `ping` time to google goes from 20 ms to 40 ms

My questions are as follows:

- How come that the Ookla speed test ever measures better speeds than `iperf` between the two laptops on the local network?
- Why my `ping` time to the laptop on the local network varies so much?
- Is there something wrong with my home router (would I get better streaming performance on my bedtime tablet with some other home router)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is the problem only with the tablet?

Comment: @harrymc No, the streaming performance is bad on all devices I tried (although all devices were wifi-connected).

Comment: What router do you have? Is it the stock one from your provider, or a third party one that you bought?

Comment: If there are other routers in the neighbourhood, you could try to find the least used channel, and switch to that one.

Comment: @zcoop98 It is a Netgear N450. It only has a 2.4GHz WiFi antenna that in practice indeed caps somewhere around 80Mbps. I'm waiting for a Linksys AC1000 dual-band router to arrive so I can confirm that the bottleneck is in the WiFi part of my modem-router.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille How do I find the least used channel?

Comment: There are a number of apps that can measure the used channels in your environment.  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=android+app+analyze+channel+usages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ookla speed test results vary a lot, from 11/55 Mbps (upstream/downstream) to 6/12 Mbps in just a couple of seconds.

It's difficult to even guess, because there *is* a lot between your devices and the Ookla test servers. It could be sudden radio interference causing the device to switch to a lower Wi-Fi rate (or even to a different band), but it could also be the Ookla website offering you different servers to test against, or it could be your local Internet connection (i.e. the physical cable in "cable" or the phone line in DSL or whatever) having some kind of problem, or the ISP having issues with its "upstream" providers, or something entirely different.

You should minimize the amount of variables. If you think the local Wi-Fi is the problem, then iperf-test a Wi-Fi connected device against a *local* Ethernet-connected device, to rule out any fluctuations on the ISP side. And vice versa, if you think the Internet connection (i.e. link with the ISP) is the problem, you again should do an online Ookla speed test *from* an Ethernet-connected device, to rule out any environment changes that could affect Wi-Fi.

> How come that the Ookla speed test ever measures better speeds than iperf between the two laptops on the local network?

In general, tests between two Wi-Fi devices on the same channel will often be worse than tests between a Wi-Fi device and an Ethernet-connected one. The problem is that there's no direct communication between devices even on the same network – all data has to be relayed through the access point (which is acting as a L2 bridge).

And as Wi-Fi is half-duplex, the two hops cannot both occur at once – if I understand things correctly, the access point cannot receive the second packet from device A if it's still sending the first one to device B. This means that in total, only half the expected amount of data can go from A to B in the same duration. (The same doesn't happen if one side is Ethernet, as then both links can be active simultaneously; nor if both sides are wired, as Ethernet is no longer a shared-medium system these days.)

> ping time from one of my laptops to the other goes from 2 ms to 200 ms while ping time to google goes from 20 ms to 40 ms

Battery-powered devices often use a "power saving" mode in their Wi-Fi radios. As far as I understand, after the interface has been idle for some amount of time, it will spend most of the time *powered off* and will only wake up every X ms to check if the AP says it has new packets queued for that device.

This way, Wi-Fi "power saving" can indeed save a lot of power but also cause very noticeable (and irregular) latency for packets incoming to that device, as it won't notice your pings until the next poll. (Meanwhile if the device itself speaks first – e.g. if it sends a 'ping' request and waits for reply – then its radio is still active and able to immediately receive the inbound response as soon as it's there.)

Try to run a continuous `ping` *from* the laptop (on Windows that's the `-t` option) or make sure some other network activity is continuously happening – now when you ping that laptop from another device, the response should be immediate as its Wi-Fi radio no longer goes to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

If performance improves when you're right next to the access point, I'd say your router is weak or your walls are particularly signal destructive. Also check and make sure the router isn't clogged with dust, it could be throttling itself if it has that capability. You could also set up a virtual router on one of the devices using pfsense and plugging the access point into the laptop and testing your speed to know if there's an issue with the router performance as opposed to the access point's performance.